# Is there any simple way to apply or map a function F to each 2 elements of a list but without Partition?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know that

```
F /@ {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

produces

```
{F[a],F[b],F[c],F[d],F[e],F[f]}
```

It can also be rewritten as

```
F @@@ Partition[{a,b,c,d,e,f},1]
```

## Question

If I want to produce

```
{F[a,b],F[c,d],F[e,f]}
```

for the same list

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

is there any other simpler ways than the following?

```
F @@@ Partition[{a,b,c,d,e,f},2]
```

Comment: And what is wrong with `F @@@ Partition[{a,b,c,d,e,f},2]` ? which kind of features are you looking for in a different solution?

Comment: @rhermans: I am looking for the built-in function if any.

Comment: ``Developer`PartitionMap``

Comment: Maybe `Partition[data, 2, 2, {1, -1}, 0, F]`

Comment: @Coolwater: Without `Partition` rather than with `Partition`. Make it shorter rather than make it longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BlockMap` and `` Developer`PartitionMap `` do pretty the same thing in this case and they are roughly of same speed.

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000000}];
F = Sin[#1 - #2] &;
a = BlockMap[F @@ # &, data, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Developer`PartitionMap[F @@ # &, data, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a === b
```

> 0.94367
>
> 0.927
>
> True

This is however not as fast as your original version:

```
a1 = F @@@ Partition[data, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a === a1
```

> 0.58
>
> True

It may be also worthwhile to replace `F` by a function `G` with vector argument, because this circumvents `Apply`.

```
G = Sin[First[#] - Last[#]] &;
a2 = BlockMap[G, data, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b2 = Developer`PartitionMap[G, data, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a === a2 === b === b2
```

> 0.24
>
> 0.23
>
> True

But if `F` is `Listable` or composed of functions with the attribute `Listable` (like in our case), the following allows us to exploit that:

```
a3 = F[data[[1 ;; ;; 2]], data[[2 ;; ;; 2]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a4 = F @@ Transpose[Partition[data, 2]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a === a3 === a4

0.0029

0.0065

True
```

In this case, `data` is a packed array and the components of `F` are very well vectorized functions. So this will not as efficient in other, less specific cases.
Moreover, `a4` might become more performant than `a3` when the length of the sublists increases.